# How to Load HBASE table into HDFS using MAP-REDUCE java program

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, hdfs

How to write a `MAP-REDUCE` java program for loading any table from `HBASE` into `HDFS`?

Instead of using the following command,

how can i write a `TRANSFORMATION` using `MAP-REDUCE` java program which will export any table from `HBASE` & load into `HDFS`??

```
bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Driver export hdfs://user/etc***
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [code of the Export](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hbase/trunk/hbase-server/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/Export.java?revision=1342856&view=markup) function that comes with hbase